# how to apply css class on body tag using c# files

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using ASP.NET MVC3 with razor engine.I want to apply css class on body tag according to page call.
I want to add class name in child page and it will affect on layout page which has body tag.
and don't want to use jquery because it execute after page render.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all jQuery's .ready function executes after the DOM is available so it's the optimal moment to start interaction with your page's elements. ( http://api.jquery.com/ready/ ) If you experience a behavior that results in styles 'flicker' you may wan't to apply display:none to body element, and removing it after you css class has been applied.

but if you really don't want to use jQuery you should consider either making a variable to hold your css class name as a part of a viewmodel your controller will be sending to Views, or going with ViewBag.CssClass that should be declared in each of your controller's actions (or in base controller's OnActionExecuting method.

Thing to consider here is understanding and following MVC pattern, where View and Business Logic should be separated. So in my opinion you should rather avoid involving controllers in view building process.

Answer (score 5):

While you may have full control of the HTML a solution was what was needed so here is one ;-)

In the _layout.cshtml page

```
<body class="@RenderSection("BodyClass", false)">
```

This will look for a section in all the child pages but says don't worry if it can't find one

Then in your child views just do this

```
@section BodyClass {productList}
```

Keep it on one line and then the outputted HTML will look fine, also you can then build up the class names as well.

```
@section BodyClass {productList generic}
```

This idea goes perfect with DOM-Ready page specific code, why not checkout 
http://paulirish.com/2009/markup-based-unobtrusive-comprehensive-dom-ready-execution/

Or my extended version here
https://github.com/AaronLayton/H5BP-Core

My way lets you do page specific code, but allows you to keep all of the Javascript in separate pages so each page becomes easily manageable. The final step would be to concatenate and minify all the JS into 1 file ;-)

Comment: I have used this method for a while, but it doesn't like the single line section statement in MVC 4.  Have you also seen this with MVC 4?  Any ideas?

Comment: I just found the answer.  I will post it below.

Answer (score 2):

Aaron's answer above works great for MVC 3, but I found that MVC 4 chokes on the single line section statement:

```
@section BodyClass {productList}
```

Instead, you need to use:

```
@section BodyClass {@("productList")}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's much easier to simply put the following in your main layout

```
<body class="@ViewBag.BodyClass">
```

Then in the content pages put:

```
@{
    ViewBag.BodyClass = "myClass";
}
```

Problem solved!